# Implicit template overloading

Tags: c++, templates, casting, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

I am creating a fixed length string class library in C++ the be used on devices with limited memory. The idea is that I can declare variables like fixed_string<10> which will result in a structure of length 11 ( to preserve space for the closing '\0', but that will be hidden from the user).

The structure looks as following:

```
template<int N> class fixed_string ;

template<>
class fixed_string<0>
{
     . . . 
}

template<int N>
class fixed_string : public fixed_string<0> {
    . . .
}
```

I am trying to fit any operator overloads in the implementation<0>:

```
template<>
class fixed_string<0>
{
    fixed_string & operator+= ( const char ch ) {
        append(ch);
        return *this;
    }
    fixed_string & operator+= ( const fixed_string & fs) {
        for(char ch : fs)
             append(ch);
        return *this;
    }
}
```

I can create fixed_length strings with the following declarations:

```
fixed_string<20> fs1('e');
fixed_string<10> fs2('d');
```

And now I can do the following:

```
fs1 += fs2;
```

And the compiler creates a method  `fixed_string<0>::operator+=(fixed_string<0> const&)` for me which works for all operations on any `fixed_string<N>`.

My problem is with the assignment operator, as it requires a proper return type:

```
fixed_string & operator= ( const fixed_string & rhs) {
    fixed_string::reset();
    return *this += rhs;
}
```

I can call this function using explicit casting

```
(fixed_string<0>) fs = (fixed_string<0>) fs2;
```

But that would not be very user friendly. Another solution is the following:

```
template<int N>
class fixed_string : public fixed_string<0> {
 . . .
    template<int M>
    fixed_string<N> & operator= ( const fixed_string<M> & rhs) {
        reset();
        return *this += rhs;
    }
. . .
}
```

But this yields in countless functions (provided by the compiler at the instantiation of the templates) `fixed_string<10>& fixed_string<10>::operator=<20>(fixed_string<20> const&)`

Which allows me to do

```
fs = fs2;
```

But I don't want to have countless functions.

Is there any way to provide my library with automatic conversions so I don't have countless assigment-operator functions without forcing a user to cast every fixed_string to fixed_string<0> ?

Thanks,

Martin

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your structure. How can you append to `fixed_string<0>` and why does `fixed_string<N>` inherit from it?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your strange design (instead of inheriting from zero-length string, why not just create a normal class, call it fixed_string_base, and put all the functions [and possibly variables] there?), you can just provide user-defined conversion - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

```
template<int N>
class fixed_string : public fixed_string<0> {
    ...
    operator fixed_string<0>() const
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

You could also provide assignment operator in the classes with N != 0, and "inside" these functions only do the cast - compiler would inline that (if you enable optimizations), and the problem would be solved too.

Comment: The solution you provided doesn't work - the compiler can't find the conversion operator both in the specialization<0> as in the implementation<N>
Also - If I provide the assignment operator in the N != 0 classes, then it yields either a lot of functions or it will provide a like-for-like assignment operator.

Comment: The trick with assignment operator in N != 0 classes is to make it _inline_. You cannot fix everything "by hand", but if the functions is "simple", then you can be pretty sure that compiler will optimize (inline) it - but for this to be true, there must be only a simple operation that calls some common (non-templated) function. That's how templates are supposed to be used - a lot of STL code is done that way - there's a common, non-templated class (like "list_base"), which is used in the public API (like "std::list")